# Print L and U matrices calculated by SuperLU using scipy

Tags: io, scipy

How can I print sparse L and U matrices calculated by `splu`, which uses SuperLU?

My MWE:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> import scipy.sparse
>>> import scipy.sparse.linalg
>>> from numpy import array
>>> M = scipy.array([ [19,0,21,21,0],[12,21,0,0,0],[0,12,16,0,0],[0,0,0,5,21],[12,12,0,0,18] ])
>>> cscM = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(M)
>>> lu_obj = scipy.sparse.linalg.splu(cscM)
>>> b = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> lu_obj.solve(b)
array([ 0.01245301,  0.08812209,  0.12140843, -0.08505639,  0.21072771])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 

`lu_obj = scipy.sparse.linalg.splu(A)
L,R = lu_obj.L, lu_obj.R`

in the current scipy version, which returns the matrices in csc format ([scipy docs)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.SuperLU.html).

Answer (score 2):

Glancing through the [scipy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.splu.html) and [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.12.0/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py#L162), scipy.sparse.linalg.splu does indeed use SuperLU.  It looks like SuperLU may not explicitly calculate L or U.  L & U are apt to be more dense than your original sparse matrix, so it makes sense to avoid storing them if they are not needed.  If it is any consolation, your `lu_obj` does contain the permutaion info for L & U: `lu_obj.perm_c, lu_obj.perm_r`.

To get L & U, the path of least work is to use `scipy.linalg.lu` to get the LU matrixes.  You'll have to convert your sparse matrixes to dense ones, though.  ie

```
P, L, U = scipy.linalg.lu(cscM.todense())
```

Comment: Dear @matt, I need L and U matrices. Solutions via using any tool (e.g. `pysparse`, etc.) are appreciated. A `C` routine that prints L and U matrices will be wonderful!

Comment: Pysparse does not do this either. The easiest way to go about it would be to change the SuperLU wrapper in Scipy so that it can convert the SuperLU format matrixes to scipy format matrices. The SuperLU matrix format is probably not very obscure.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but unfortunately converting those matrices to dense ones is very likely to cause an "out of memory" error for sufficiently big matrices. Is there any other way to do it?