# If the sparse L and U matrices from the LU decomposition of A are stored in scipy.sparse.linalg.splu, how do I call them?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a big sparse matrix A that I want to apply the LU-decomposition to. This is a slow process so I looked into using scipy.sparse.linalg.splu in order to compute the L and U matrix in sparse format from the sparse A matrix directly. However, I'm not sure what this command actually returns. From the example given [here](http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/~francois.denis/IAAM1/scipy-html-1.0.0/generated/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.splu.html). I can't make out what is actually happening and what the result following from B.solve(x) actually represents. What I want to do is use the sparse matrix L and U separately, so I need to find a way to get them out of this scipy.sparse.linalg.splu ''element'', in *sparse* form, so I can use them. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746167/print-l-and-u-matrices-calculated-by-superlu-using-scipy) post gives some help but only on how to extract the L and U matrix in dense form. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question and describe the behavior, otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Both links claim  that `lu_obj.L` and `lu_obj.U` are sparse.

Comment: @hpaulj For some reason everything worked after I read your reply. I must've been misunderstanding the posts I linked. Anyway, thanks alot!